# How to use share content to specific friend's wall on Facebook from an iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

It's straightforward to use Facebook the Javascript SDK and FB.ui to trigger the "feed" dialog to share on your wall.

However, this shares on your wall with everyone.  I'm looking for a way to share on a specific friend's wall and not finding any answers in the Facebook dev documentation.

I was about to give up but them saw [this article](http://www.lockergnome.com/social/2011/06/08/now-you-can-share-on-facebook-with-a-friend-or-group/) written June 2011 which shows FB sharing UI that shows that you can change the scope of your sharing:

[image: Screenshot of FB sharing dialog with scoping]

I can't find any information that shows how to trigger this dialog that exposes those options. I've used this sample code from [FB dev docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // assume we are already logged in
      FB.init({appId: '1234567890', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
           link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/'
          });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this bring up a dialog that is essentially like the following. Notice no scoping options like the earlier screenshot:

[image]

Note: Even though I'm asking about the Javascript SDK and showing HTML, I ultimately I want to use the Facebook iOS SDK to share a link from my iOS app to an individual friend of the user that's logged into my app (while letting that user select which friend to share to).

Answer (score 1):

Our feed dialogs do not allow posting to another user's wall. To do this, I would suggest using our [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) which allows the developer to specify the recipient user (end user can add additional users once the dialog is rendered).

It can be rendered via the graph api as such:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&
name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&
link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Comment: I don't understand how it's possed that the article I cited has the screenshot I showed. It's clearly showing that you can scope it.  The FB dev docs says that the Send dialog sends the message as a private message, and doesn't post to the wall. Are the docs incorrect? (I forgot to mention that I ultimately plan to use this within our iOS app)

Comment: So for the send dialog's `to` field it states, 'A user ID or username to which to send the message. Once the dialog comes up, the user can specify additional users, Facebook groups, and email addresses to which to send the message.' So no it's not possible directly on your side but is still possible in this dialog. Which is all private, you're correct - you can post to profile via the send button, but not evidently though the dialog api :-/ I'll file a bug.

Comment: However, you should still be able to specify the `to` field in the [field dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which will post a story from your user to another user's wall. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug, looks like I want to use the `send` dialog but need to have that bug fixed. The only way I can see to do it currently is to use the `feed` dialog, but precede it with my own custom friend picker UI where my user chooses the friend, then passes that in for the value of the `to` field.  It looks like there is another bug as well since the dev docs seem to imply I should be able to pick friends from the `feed` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only place a dialog like that shows up is via the sharer.php endpoint, e.g. https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com.  That endpoint appears to have been deprecated (there's a [Quora thread](http://www.quora.com/Will-Facebook-get-rid-of-sharer-php-soon) about it), but it's still functional for now.

It's possible the sharer dialog used to be available as a UI method, but as far as I can tell that's no longer the case, so opening up sharer.php in your app is the only way to show those scoping options.  It's clunky in mobile browsers, however - your custom friend picker followed by a `feed` dialog is arguably a more attractive solution.